# Composition of unitary operator with its dual is the identity

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely unitary operators. In the text, the author gives the following proposition without proof:

> **Proposition**: Let $U\colon H\to H$ be an unitary operator, i.e. $\langle Ux, Uy \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle$ for all $x,y\in H$ and $\text{Im}U=H$. Then $UU^*=I=U^*U$; that is, $U$ is invertible and $U^{-1}=U^*$.

I'm unsure how to show that $UU^*=I=U^*U$; however, under the assumption it holds, I believe I can show that $U^{-1}=U^*$ with the following argument:

The dual of $U$, we call it $U^*$, is the unique operator that satisfies $\langle Ux, y \rangle = \langle x, U^*y \rangle$ or all $x,y\in H$. Notice
$$
\langle Ux, y \rangle=\langle Ux, Iy \rangle=\langle Ux, UU^{-1}y \rangle=\langle x, U^{-1}y \rangle.
$$
Whence $U^*=U^{-1}$.

Comment: You are already implicitely assuming that $U$ is invertible.

Comment: I guess a better way is to write $$\langle x,y\rangle =\langle Ux, Uy\rangle =\langle x, U^*Uy\rangle.$$ As this holds for all $x$, we get $U^*Uy=y$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: I see thanks.

Comment: If $UU^*=I=U^*U$, then $U^*=U^{-1}$ by definition (the two are equivalent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you assumed that $U$ is invertible, but this needs to be shown first. Rather, proceed as follows:

- From the assumption: $U$ is isometric. Show that this implies that $U^*U = I$. In particular, $U$ is injective.
- From the assumption: $U$ is surjective. Hence, a left inverse for $U$ is also a right inverse and thus $UU^* = I$.

Comment: Thanks, I see where my thinking went wrong.

Comment: I guess you mean $U^*U=I$ instead of $UU^*=I$ (if you conclude that $U$ is injective)?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Yes of course thanks for catching this error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **hint** towards a simpler proof: a bounded operator $A$ is the identity if and only if for all $x,y$ we have $\langle Ax,y\rangle =\langle x,y\rangle$.